# Network with 2 vlan and IP forward

Tags: networking, router, dns, ip

I've got 2 VLAN configured in a router.
VLAN1 10.0.1.x
VLAN2 10.0.2.x

One of my server is on the VLAN2 only. I called it "control-server". From it, I can ping the ip address 10.0.1.4 but not the 10.0.1.7.
All the traceroute pass trough the gateway is a server which is doing  IP forward to external network and it's connected on both VLANs.(IP adress 10.0.2.9 and 10.0.1.9)

These are both traceroutes from call-server.

```
traceroute 10.0.1.4
traceroute: Warning: Multiple interfaces found; using 10.0.2.12 @ nge0
traceroute to 10.0.1.4 (10.0.1.4), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  server-eth1 (10.0.2.9)  0.230 ms  0.148 ms  0.155 ms
 2  host4 (10.0.1.4)  0.169 ms  0.133 ms  0.146 ms

traceroute 10.0.1.7
traceroute: Warning: Multiple interfaces found; using 10.0.2.12 @ nge0
traceroute to 10.0.1.7 (10.0.1.7), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  server-eth1 (10.0.2.9)  0.217 ms  0.158 ms  0.081 ms
 2 ****
```

The odder is from 10.0.1.7 I can ping 10.0.2.12 or "control-server" hostname.

Any advise are welcome.

Comment: Note, ping 10.0.2.7 is working well from control-server, but I've got hostname problem.

Comment: Which is the default gateway configured in the equipment with the IP address 10.0.1.7?

Comment: it's 10.0.2.9 on Iface eth1

Comment: Must be 10.0.1.9

Comment: It's the same than the device with the IP address 10.0.1.4. However I change the IP address of the GW to 10.0.1.9 and that didn't solve the problem

Comment: Usually it's a problem of  GW or netmask. have you checked it in all devices?

Comment: Sorry for the delay I didn't see your add. That worked before. To be honest, on host7 server, I did migration from RHEL5.11 to RHEL6.6. Host4 is stilling on RHEL5.11. All netmask are in /24. Gateway always the same.